# SAS equivalent to R’s is.element()

Tags: sas, duplicates, unique, subset

It’s the first time that I’ve opened sas today and I’m looking at some code a colleague wrote.

So let’s say I have some data (`import`) where duplicates occur but I want only those which have a unique number named VTNR.

First she looks for unique numbers:

```
    data M.import;
    set M.import;

    by VTNR;
    if first.VTNR=1 then unique=1;
    run;
```

Then she creates a table with the duplicated numbers:

```
    data M.import_dup1;
    set M.import;

    where unique^=1;
    run;
```

And finally a table with all duplicates.
But here she is really hardcoding the numbers, so for example:

```
    data M.import_dup2;
    set M.import;
    where VTNR in (130001292951,130100975613,130107546425,130108026864,130131307133,130134696722,130136267001,130137413257,130137839451,130138291041);
    run;
```

I’m sure there must be a better way.

Since I’m only familiar with R I would write something like:

```
import_dup2 <- subset(import, is.element(import$VTNR, import_dup1$VTNR))
```

I guess there must be something like the `$` also for sas?

Comment: Look at proc sort with the uniqueout and Dupout options.

Comment: If you want help from SAS programmers then you will need to explain what your R code does.  Also you should explain what problem you are trying to solve using the R code not just how it works.  In general you need to adapt your approach to problems when using different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks like the most direct translation of the R code

```
import_dup2 <- subset(import, is.element(import$VTNR, import_dup1$VTNR))
```

Would be to use SQL code

```
proc sql;
 create table import_dup2 as 
   select * from import
   where VTNR in (select VTNR from import_dup1)
 ;
quit;
```

But if your intent is to find the observations in IMPORT that have more than one observation per VTNR value there is no need to first create some other table.

```
data import_dup2 ;
  set import;
  by VTNR ;
  if not (first.VTNR and last.VTNR);
run;
```

Comment: Note that to use `by` the dataset must be sorted by that variable.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the options in PROC SORT.
Make sure to specify an OUT= dataset otherwise you'll overwrite your original data.

```
/*Generate fake data with dups*/
data class;
set sashelp.class sashelp.class(obs=5);
run;

/*Create unique and dup dataset*/
proc sort data=class nouniquekey uniqueout=uniquerecs out=dups;
by name;
run;

/*Display results - for demo*/
proc print data=uniquerecs;
title 'Unique Records';
run;

proc print data=dups;
title 'Duplicate Records';
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Above solution can give you duplicates but not unique values. There are many possible ways to do both in SAS. Very easy to understand would be a SQL solution.

```
proc sql;
create table no_duplicates as
    select *
        from import
        group by VTNR
        having count(*) = 1
    ;
create table all_duplicates as
    select *
        from import
        group by VTNR
        having count(*) > 1
    ;
quit;
```

Comment: I can understand your approach but I'm really looking for something like the `is.element()`-way (and the `$`), as I find it very usefull for all kinds of subsetting. Or this doesn't exist in sas?

Comment: SAS Base is not a matrix language. If you have access to SAS/IML you can do vector comparisons. But in IML you can as well just use R code.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Reeza's or Tom's solution, but for completeness, the solution *most* similar to R (and your preexisting code) would be three steps.  Again, I wouldn't use this here, it's excess work for something you can do more easily, but the concept is helpful in other situations.

First, get the dataset of duplicates - either her method, or `proc sort`.

```
proc sort nodupkey data=have out=nodups dupout=dups;
  by byvar;
run;
```

Then pull those into a macro list:

```
proc sql;
  select byvar 
    into :duplist separated by ','
    from dups;
quit;
```

Then you have them in `&duplist.` and can use them like so:

```
data want;
  set have;
  if not (byvar in &duplist.);
run;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
data want;
   set import;
   where VTNR in import_dup1;
run;
```

Comment: This look like exactly what I want to achieve but when I type in the following code, zero lines are produced. 
`data M.want;
   set M.import;
   where VTNR in M.import_dup1;
run;`
(I've also tried without the `M.` with the same result.)

Comment: It will be very helpful if you could provide a small example data.

Comment: I'm loading a csv.File which I can not upload here. But VTNR is a best32. if this makes any difference. So the "missing" `M.` is not causing the problem?

Comment: That is not valid code.  The IN operator wants a list of values.  It cannot use a variable name.  And it definitely cannot use a dataset name.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please edit your answer to add some explanation.